# The python error TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, azure, azure-speech

I am using Azure Speech Recognition services and I'm having trouble
creating commands.

I'm using interpreter Python 3.10.4

Code:

```
def takeCommand():
    
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language="tr-TR"

    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    text = "Dinliyorum..."
    speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
    query = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()
    
    if query.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        print("Recognized: {}".format(query.text))
    elif query.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        print("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(query.no_match_details))
    elif query.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = query.cancellation_details
        print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
            print("Did you set the speech resource key and region values?")
```

> i get this error when i check input from microphone and ask it to respond.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
      wishMe()
      
      while True:
            
            query = takeCommand()
            
            if 'Nasılsın' in query:
                  text = "Teşekkürler, İyiyim Sen Nasılsın?"
                  speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "------------", line 58, in 
> if 'Nasılsın' in query:
> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: `takeCommand()` does not return a value, therefore it returns `None` by default.

Comment: How can I check the text I receive from the microphone?

Comment: you have to `return query` at the end of your function

Comment: "TypeError: argument of type 'SpeechRecognitionResult' is not iterable " i have new error huh..

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mention above you need to add

```
return query
```

to the end of your takeCommand() method. This will return the SpeechRecognitionResult.

Then, since you want to match on the recognized text, you'll need to modify the your condition to check the "text" property in the returned SpeechRecognitionResult:

```
if 'Nasılsın' in query.text:
```